# Where can I download the Remote Debugger for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

About six weeks ago I set up remote debugging on a couple of our servers to enable us to remotely debug applications that were created in Visual Studio 2017.  However, I want to install remote debugging onto a different server but can't now seem to find a source from which to download the remote debugging software - it looks as if the source has been removed by Microsoft since the release of Visual Studio 2019.

Can someone point me to a reliable source for the software?  I stupidly didn't keep a copy of the download when I pulled it down before.  Alternatively, is the remote debugging software available as part of the actual installation software for VS2017?

Comment: *"I stupidly didn't keep a copy of the download"* - that's not stupid. We rely on big companies support for years after purchases. Usually it works. It's someone stupid there.

Comment: The download location in the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#download-and-install-the-remote-tools) is just fine, it offers both version 15.0 (original release) and 15.9 (latest and greatest).  You do need a valid Microsoft account to access the "benefits".  And presumably it needs to be aware that you have a license for VS2017.  Click the Subscriptions link on the download page, "Where is my subscription?" might be relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have VS2017 pro licence and I've used same account to access "benefits". But I don't have MSDN subscription, indeed, and that's probably the problem. Earlier download was not under pay-wall, I could just google for "remote debugging 2017 download" and get it without log in or anything. So my (OP too?) question is how to get that benefit again if possible.

Comment: "We rely on big companies support for years after purchases" ahahahahahaaaaa

Answer (score 32):

Code from my [Remote Debugging Easy](https://www.turbo-play.com/rde/):

```
    if (RDV == 2022)
    {
        if (ARCH == 64)
            d = FetchX("https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/964531996/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe");
        else
            d = FetchX("https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/964531996/RemoteTools.x86ret.enu.exe");
    }
    else
    if (RDV == 2019)
    {
        if (ARCH == 64)
            d = Fetch("https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe");
        else
            d = Fetch("https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/RemoteTools.x86ret.enu.exe");
    }
    else
    if (RDV == 2017)
    {
        if (ARCH == 64)
            d = Fetch("https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe");
        else
            d = Fetch("https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/RemoteTools.x86ret.enu.exe");
    }
    else // 2015
    {
        if (ARCH == 64)
            d = Fetch("https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/A/E7AEA696-A4EB-48DD-BA4A-9BE41A402400/rtools_setup_x64.exe");
        else
            d = Fetch("https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/A/E7AEA696-A4EB-48DD-BA4A-9BE41A402400/rtools_setup_x86.exe");
    }
```

Using links from [this msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019) (when they used to work :P). It has also the links for older versions.

EDIT: Added VS 2022 remote debugging tools.

Comment: Just to clarify: msdn links don't worki if you don't join Visual Studio Dev Essentials or purchase Visual Studio Subscription.

Answer (score 20):

If you have VS2017 installed, then you can copy the whole

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger

folder (adjust path accordingly) to a target machine and run `msvsmon.exe` there.

Comment: This is the path for VS2015 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64`

Comment: Hope this still works, I've tried to download https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202019 -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022, I barely got in with my Github account, and I get "Sorry, we couldn’t find your subscription". At least they should write that a subscription are needed, Microsoft assholes